# Google Game Service error ratio of 100%: how to solve it?

Tags: firebase, google-api

My Android application is linked to a Google Game Services project which was working until some days ago. 
However, now its error ratio is 100%. Failure of every request. 
It is not my application. Indeed, its errors occurs even when I try to open the leaderboard on Play Games.

I do not want to create another application, so I want to solve it. 
what can I do ?

For example, I have a leaderboard in the Play Game, that does not open in the Play Games application (the application that comes within Android).

In the application I am develloping, it is the same, I try to open the leaderboard with the code:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(MyApplication.getAppContext(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                        Log.d("LeaderBoard","onSuccess");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
                    }

                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("LeaderBoard",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Failed to open the leaderboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

It just open a blue screen for two seconds that just closes without showing any leaderboard.

I tryed to create a new leaderboard, which was successfuly created, but it started to happen the same with this one after I tryied to add a score to it:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);
```

These codes were working before. It stopped working without any apparent reason.

<< Informations about the project >>

**gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle(Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cerveja.qof.pedro.qof_cerveja"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    )
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    //
    //
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:7.6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:7.6.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:7.0.1.0'
    //implementation files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.6.2.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you add some images or codes that you are trying to use in your project , attach a picture of the **Gradle**  file within the question, this will help to identify and solve the problem

Comment: I added all the information you required. Hope you can help.

Comment: It seems you need to create a new query "json", upload a new "json" file to your project and then try again, Google Play refuses to contact the application of the incompatibility between the address of Google's **SH1**  with the address inside your project currently
The code you use is completely free of errors and there are no inconsistencies in the code
If this does not work, I can write a new code that will help you better

Comment: Can you explain better, Ivan?
I tried to upload the SHA1 key into the firebase project, but I get an error.

Comment: PS: The application is loggin in to the Play Games.

Comment: If you can send me a code that helps to solve the problem, I'd be glad.

Comment: I uptaded the SHA1 key but the problem was not solved.